# SQL Server 17.4 Developer Edition Compatibility Levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

In SQL Server 2017 Express, v17.4, I am unable to select a compatibility level beyond 2008 (100). The only versions available are 2008 or older. I am training for the MCSA SQL Server developer exams and I want to test some functionality unique to SQL Server 2016 (130) but am unable to do so until I figure out this problem. I did do my best to search here and on Google, but I'm not finding even a slightest reference to this. Is it a limitation of using a free version of SQL Server? As an alternative solution, is there a way to download older developer edition versions of SQL Server that might contain 2016 DB compatibility?

Comment: What version do you get reported when you run `SELECT @@VERSION` ?? Are you using only **Management Studio** v17 ??  THat's just the management GUI - **NOT** the database engine! But the features available (including compatibility levels) depend on the **database engine** you're connected to (its version) - not the management GUI you're using to connect to that engine....

Comment: The latest version of SQL Server 2017 is `RTM-CU3-GDR` or Version `14.0.3015.40`. This definitely sounds like you're quoting your SSMS version, as SQL Server latest edition is only on Version 14 (there is no version 17).

Comment: I'll have to check when I get home; i'm at work now. Although there is a good chance I need to update the database engine like you say. I had thought I downloaded the full package, as I've not used SQL Server on my home PC before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download SQL Server Developer edition from Visual Studio Dev Essentials https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=SQL%20Server%202017

Or from here 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql-server/sql-server-downloads